# How to import and using normal js files (not in modules) in a React project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I start a new project in React 17, and using create-react-app.

Now i have to import some js and css files into the project ,but the js file is write like this :

```
(function(b){

  var JGOcx = { ... },
      JGTimeOut = { ... },
   
    ....

}(window);
```

I don't think this file i can easily using in a React project,I just want to use a "JGOcx" object , what should I do ?

wait for answers ...

Comment: Notice the argument to the function is `window`, meaning this code will sooner or later define global variables accessible from anywhere, so just `import "file.js";` and pretend the exposed variables are exposed because they're exposed.

Comment: Not possible to any reasonable extent given the code in your question